# custom class calling function - too many input arguments

Tags: matlab, class

I'm learning about MATLAB classes they certainly seem different to what I'm used to. Below is an example class I'm using.

I initialise my class with the line below,

```
myClass = ClassTest(3);
```

This is fine. The issue I have is calling the RunMain function.

**First call**

```
 myClass.RunMain(myClass)
```

I get the error message `too many inputs`.

**Second call**

```
 myClass.RunMain(myClass, anything)
```

This call works. However, I find it strange I need to supply a second parameter which is never used - just seem messy. Sure I'm missing something here.

```
classdef ClassTest < handle

properties
   myNum; 
   myDate = datenum(date);
end

methods

    function ct = ClassTest(someNum)
        ct.myNum = someNum;            
    end

    % this function does not work when called
    %function RunMain(obj)            
    %    obj.myNum = obj.myNum * 2;
    %    disp(obj.myNum);
    %end

    % this works
    function RunMain(obj, anything)            
        obj.myNum = obj.myNum * 2;
        disp(obj.myNum);
    end

end
```

**Update**

I can see when I debug that the `anything` parameter is exactly the same as obj even `obj.myNum` has changed value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct syntax for calling a method where myClass is an object of the class defining the method RunMain is:

In case of `function RunMain(obj)` it is one of these:

```
 myClass.RunMain()
 RunMain(myClass)
```

In case of `function RunMain(obj, anything)` it is one of these:

```
 myClass.RunMain(anything)
 RunMain(myClass, anything)
```

You can find more details regarding syntax here:
http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/ordinary-methods.html